# How to install Predis on app service?

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service, predis

I am using azure app service My application requires Predis extension to be installed on the server, how can I have it installed on App services? Application is in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can package the Predis SDK in your application and deploy to Azure Web Apps Service together via GIT or FTP. [Create a PHP-MySQL web app in Azure App Service and deploy using Git](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-mysql-deploy-use-git/) for more info.

Additionally, you can just simply configure the Predis SDK in composer.json.

```
"require": {
        "predis/predis": "1.*"
    }
```

Then install the composer extension in your Azure Web Apps Service. Then when you deploying to Azure via Git, the Azure deployment task will run composer install command to install the dependencies and composer commands configured in the file.

You can refer to [How to install composer on app service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35035504/how-to-install-composer-on-app-service) for installing composer extension

Additionally, if you leverage Redis Cache in Azure, you should Enable the non-SSL endpoint for PHP integration at first:
[image]

And the code snippet:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Predis\Client('redis://{your_redis_service_name}.redis.cache.windows.net');
$client->auth('{password key}');
$client->set('foo', 'bar');
$value = $client->get('foo');
echo $value;
```