# PHP script cannot access 'Vendor' folder for Azure website

Tags: php, azure, sendgrid, access-denied, vendor

**Background:**

I am using Azure App Services to host a php website.   I’m new to Azure and PHP (programming in general for that matter).  As a starting point I have been following a set of PHP tutorials.  The tutorial that I am currently on requires that I use the PHP mail function, however this fails, and from what I’ve read it is because I need to use the SendGrid mail service when working with an Azure hosted website.

**Steps Taken:**

First I installed SendGrid from the Azure market place.  I then installed Composer to my project directory (‘wwwroot’) followed by installing the dependencies.  I tried using both ‘sendgrid/smtpapi’ and ‘sendgrid/sendgrid-php’ as dependencies in the ‘composer.json’ file.  The installations appeared successful and the “Vendor” folder (in “wwwroot”) updated with files for “Composer” and “SendGrid”.

I tried a number of code examples for SendGrid but decided to stick with the one below (it seems simpler)

```
// using SendGrid's PHP Library
// https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$sendgrid = new SendGrid("SENDGRID_APIKEY");

$email    = new SendGrid\Email();

$email->addTo("test@sendgrid.com")
      ->setFrom("you@youremail.com")
      ->setSubject("Sending with SendGrid is Fun")
      ->setHtml("and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");

$sendgrid->send($email);
```

**Problem:**Error’.  When I look at the detailed error logs I get a further error ‘HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found’.

I know that the file ‘vendor/autload.php’ required by the mail script does exist

When I run the website the mail script breaks with a ‘500.0 - Internal Server as I can see it from the FTP portal.

However, if I try to browse to the ‘Vendor’ folder via the ‘Kudu’ site, a “Session Expired” error occurs (strangely it only happens for this specific folder).  Internet Explorer developer tools show a further error of “403 Forbidden - Access Denied’

**Conclusion:**

It is my conclusion that the mail script breaks because it cannot access the files required from the ‘Vendor’ folder.  I however do not know why or how to work around this.  Any recommendations will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry guys, something seems to have gone wrong with the first paragraph in the "Problem" section:

When I run the website the mail script breaks with a ‘500.0 - Internal Server Error’....

Answer (score 1):

As I created a new test project on Azure Web Apps to send emails via SendGird SDK. I didn't reproduce your issue, here are my steps to build the SendGird project, FYI:

- Install Visual Studio Online extension and Composer extension of the Azure Web Apps for easy developing and management. You can refer the answer of [How to install composer on app service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35035504/how-to-install-composer-on-app-service/35058312#35058312) for the steps to install the extensions
- Create the `composer.json` file in the root directory of the application. The content of the file:

`{ 
  "require": {
    "sendgrid/sendgrid": "~4.0"
  }
}`

- Open Console the run the command `composer install` to install the dependency.

My test code is the same with you, and it works fine on my side. you can try these steps.