# how to store video in Microsoft window Azure code in php

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage

I am using windows azure blob storage for storing data that the users will upload to my website. My websites has been developed using the PHP and as per the documentation for

[Blob Service for PHP:](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-php-how-to-use-blobs/#ConfigureStorage)

How do incorporate those PEAR Packages into PHP to make sure that these dependencies remain resolved? I tried putting them in the libraries folder but that didn't work as I would need to load them every time they are used. I even tried setting them to autoload but without any avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try again to run the command php composer.phar install --prefer-dist - with that flag enabled Composer tries to download ZIP files of that version instead of using the command line version of Git (which seems to not be installed on your machine).

In other news, I think you can safely switch from that development version of Silex to a stable one. Remove that "@dev" tag from the Silex version requirement. There are released versions 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.1.0, 1.1.1 and 1.1.2 - one of these should work.

Answer (score 1):

General, you can manage the dependencies via Composer with `composer.json` file easily.

First, you can refer to the answer of [How to install composer on app service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35035504/how-to-install-composer-on-app-service/35058312#35058312) to install composer extension in your Azure Web Apps service.

Then create the `composer.json` file in the root directory of your site with the content:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "pear",
            "url": "http://pear.php.net"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "pear-pear.php.net/mail_mime" : "*",
        "pear-pear.php.net/http_request2" : "*",
        "pear-pear.php.net/mail_mimedecode" : "*",
        "microsoft/windowsazure": "*"
    }
}
```

Then run command `composer install` or `composer update` in cmdlet. You can leverage the Kudu Console site of your Azure Web Apps Service whose URL should be: `http://<your_site_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` or the Visual Studio Online extension to manage files and run commands.

It will download and install all the dependencies into the `vendor` folder in t he root directory of your site and will create an `autoload.php` file. After installing the dependencies, when you need to use the sdk, you need include the autoload file in the PHP script: `require_once '/vendor/autoload.php'`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to create a php and mysql website running on azure, so you need to follow this tutorial:

[here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-mysql-deploy-use-git/)