# Migrate azure mobile service table script (Blob upload) to azure app service

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services, visual-studio-cordova, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I'm migrating my app from the old azure mobile service to the new azure app service.

And in the old azure mobile service, I use this this table script to insert to my image table.

```
var azure = require('azure');
var qs = require('querystring');
var appSettings = require('mobileservice-config').appSettings;

function insert(item, user, request) {
// Get storage account settings from app settings. 
var accountName = appSettings.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME;
var accountKey = appSettings.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY;
var host = accountName + '.blob.core.windows.net';

if ((typeof context.item.containerName !== "undefined") && (
context.item.containerName !== null)) {
    // Set the BLOB store container name on the item, which must be lowercase.
    context.item.containerName = context.item.containerName.toLowerCase();

    // If it does not already exist, create the container 
    // with public read access for blobs.        
    var blobService = azure.createBlobService(accountName, accountKey, host);
    blobService.createContainerIfNotExists(context.item.containerName, {
        publicAccessLevel: 'blob'
    }, function (error) {
        if (!error) {

            // Provide write access to the container for the next 5 mins.        
            var sharedAccessPolicy = {
                AccessPolicy: {
                    Permissions: azure.Constants.BlobConstants.SharedAccessPermissions.WRITE,
                    Expiry: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5 * 60 * 1000)
                }
            };

            // Generate the upload URL with SAS for the new image.
            var sasQueryUrl =
            blobService.generateSharedAccessSignature(context.item.containerName,
            context.item.resourceName, sharedAccessPolicy);

            // Set the query string.
            context.item.sasQueryString = qs.stringify(sasQueryUrl.queryString);

            // Set the full path on the new new item, 
            // which is used for data binding on the client. 
            item.imageUri = sasQueryUrl.baseUrl + sasQueryUrl.path;

        } else {
            console.error(error);
        }
        context.execute();
    });
} else {
    context.execute();
}
}
```

To migrate, I rewrite it for the new app service,

```
var table = module.exports = require('azure-mobile-apps').table();
var azure = require('azure');
var qs = require('querystring');
var appSettings = require('mobileservice-config').appSettings;

function insertPhoto(context) {
// Get storage account settings from app settings. 
var accountName = appSettings.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME;
var accountKey = appSettings.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY;
var host = accountName + '.blob.core.windows.net';

if ((typeof context.item.containerName !== "undefined") && (
context.item.containerName !== null)) {
    // Set the BLOB store container name on the item, which must be lowercase.
    context.item.containerName = context.item.containerName.toLowerCase();

    // If it does not already exist, create the container 
    // with public read access for blobs.        
    var blobService = azure.createBlobService(accountName, accountKey, host);
    blobService.createContainerIfNotExists(context.item.containerName, {
        publicAccessLevel: 'blob'
    }, function (error) {
        if (!error) {

            // Provide write access to the container for the next 5 mins.        
            var sharedAccessPolicy = {
                AccessPolicy: {
                    Permissions: azure.Constants.BlobConstants.SharedAccessPermissions.WRITE,
                    Expiry: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5 * 60 * 1000)
                }
            };

            // Generate the upload URL with SAS for the new image.
            var sasQueryUrl =
            blobService.generateSharedAccessSignature(context.item.containerName,
            context.item.resourceName, sharedAccessPolicy);

            // Set the query string.
            context.item.sasQueryString = qs.stringify(sasQueryUrl.queryString);

            // Set the full path on the new new item, 
            // which is used for data binding on the client. 
            item.imageUri = sasQueryUrl.baseUrl + sasQueryUrl.path;

        } else {
            console.error(error);
        }
        context.execute();
    });
} else {
    context.execute();
}
};

table.insert(insertPhoto);
```

However when I execute it, I get an internal server error, saying

> Error: Cannot find module 'azure'

Here is the complete error log:

```
2016-05-09T19:02:06  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.
2016-05-09T19:02:23.812Z - �[31merror�[39m: Unable to load D:\home\site\wwwroot\tables\photos.js Error: Cannot find module 'azure'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)
at Object.<anonymous>
(D:\home\site\wwwroot\tables\photos.js:11:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)

Mon May 09 2016 19:02:23 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time): Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
Error: Cannot find module 'azure'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)
at Object.<anonymous>
    (D:\home\site\wwwroot\tables\photos.js:11:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
    Error: Cannot find module 'azure'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous>
        (D:\home\site\wwwroot\tables\photos.js:11:13)
        at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
        at require (module.js:385:17)
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title>IIS Detailed Error - 500.1002 - Internal Server Error</title>
            <style type="text/css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="content">
                <div class="content-container">
                    <h3>HTTP Error 500.1002 - Internal Server Error</h3>
                    <h4>The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="content-container">
                    <fieldset>
                        <h4>Most likely causes:</h4>
                        <ul>    <li>IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.</li>    <li>IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.</li>    <li>IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.</li>     <li>The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.</li>   <li>The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.</li> </ul>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div class="content-container">
                    <fieldset>
                        <h4>Things you can try:</h4>
                        <ul>    <li>Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.</li>     <li>Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.</li>  <li>Verify the permissions for the DLL.</li>    <li>Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.</li>  <li>Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439">here</a>. </li> </ul>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                <div class="content-container">
                    <fieldset>
                        <h4>Detailed Error Information:</h4>
                        <div id="details-left">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr class="alt"><th>Module</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;iisnode</td></tr>
                                <tr><th>Notification</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ExecuteRequestHandler</td></tr>
                                <tr class="alt"><th>Handler</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;iisnode</td></tr>
                                <tr><th>Error Code</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0x00000002</td></tr>

                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div id="details-right">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr class="alt"><th>Requested URL</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;http://selfiecontestdev:80/app.js</td></tr>
                                <tr><th>Physical Path</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;D:\home\site\wwwroot\app.js</td></tr>
                                <tr class="alt"><th>Logon Method</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td></tr>
                                <tr><th>Logon User</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td></tr>

                            </table>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                <div class="content-container">
                    <fieldset>
                        <h4>More Information:</h4>
                        This error means that there was a problem while processing the request. The request was received by the Web server, but during processing a fatal error occurred, causing the 500 error.
                        <p><a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&amp;IIS70Error=500,1002,0x00000002,9200">View more information &raquo;</a></p>
                        <p>Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:</p>


                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
    {"level":1,"message":"request","timestamp":1462820578207,"responseTime":0,"method":"POST","path":"/dev/api/telemetry/wwwroot/","statusCode":201}
    2016-05-09T19:04:06  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
```

What should I do to fix the script?

Comment: Have you installed the Azure SDK for node in your new App Services application before you use `require('azure')`?

Comment: Hi @GaryLiu-MSFT thanks for the reply, but how do I do that? Is there a way I can install it just using the azure online portal?

Comment: Hi @Vincent, any update?

Answer (score 1):

As the architecture of Mobile Apps is changed from Mobile Services, now the mobile apps migrate to Azure App Services.

Actually the Mobile Apps backend in Node.js is an expressjs project, and the [mobile app sdk for node](http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-node/) is a middleware of express.

So you can download your mobile app to local (refer to [How to: Download the Node.js backend quickstart code project using Git](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#download-quickstart)) ,we can leverage `package.json` file in your application's root directory to maintain the nodejs modules you need, then deploy to Azure via git, and Azure App Service will install the dependencies via deployment task. You can refer to [Using Node.js Modules with Azure applications](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/nodejs-use-node-modules-azure-apps/) for more.

Meanwhile, You can leverage Kudu Console site or Visual studio online extension to quick install nodejs module online. You can refer to the answer of [How to run django manage.py command on Azure App Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36468614/how-to-run-django-manage-py-command-on-azure-app-service/36490229#36490229) for the general idea of these online tools.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.