# Socket.IO rooms not working on Azure, but working locally

Tags: node.js, azure, iis, websocket, socket.io

I made a simple app with socket.io and node.js, it is a push notification service.
When a user connects to the websocket, sends his username (and the name of dashboard) and immediately joins to a room named as the user. The application listens for POST request, saves them and then emits a message to the user's room.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('userid', function(data) { 
      socket.join(data.userid+'-'+data.dashboard);
      notification.find({userid: data.userid, to: data.dashboard, received_by_user: false}, function(err, notifs) {
            socket.emit('get_notifications', notifs);
      }
    }
});
app.post('/notify', function(req, res, next) {
  var notif_recv = new notification(req.body);
  notif_recv.save(function (err, notif_recv) {
       io.sockets.in(notif_recv.userid+'-'+notif_recv.dashboard).emit('new_notification', notif_recv);
  });
res.send(200);
});
```

When I test it with node locally, it works fine, I send a `POST` to `/notify` and I can see the notification arriving at the dashboard. The problem is, when I test on an AppService on Azure, the client connects to the websocket and receives the first notifications (`get_notifications` event), but when I `POST` to `/notify`, the client doesn't receives anything! (no `new_notification` event, `io.sockets.in(...).emit(...)` doesnt seems to work on Azure).

For debugging purposes, I used console.log(...) to log at the server the returned value of functions `socket.join(...)` and `io.sockets.in(...).emit(...)`, resulting that `io.socket.in(...).emit(...)` seems to return a io server without any channels and connections!

IIS could be messing with it? I tend to think that IIS have different processes for `app.post('/notify'...` and `io.on('connection'...` so, the socket I am referencing on app.post is DIFFERENT from I am joining the user in `io.on('connection'..` (`socket.join(...)`).

Any tip when using socket.io rooms in Azure/IIS?
Thanks!

Comment: How do you set the port in your application? Have you tried to use `app.listen(process.env.PORT);` ?

Comment: Yes, I have `var port  = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '8090');`
I think the problem is IIS messing with Socket.IO rooms protocol...

Answer (score 0):

To test the `socket.io` and `POST` issue on Azure App Services, I simplify the project and test on Azure.

The test `server.js`:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
})); 
server.listen(process.env.PORT ||3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/client.html');
});

app.post('/notify', function(req, res, next) {
  io.sockets.emit('new_notification', req.body);
  res.send(200);
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('get_notifications', "get_notifications_:"+new Date());
});
```

The client content:

```
<body>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    var socket = io();
    $.post("/notify",{
      msg:"notification from client"
    });
    socket.on('get_notifications',function(msg){
      console.log(msg);
    });
    socket.on('new_notification',function(msg){
      console.log(msg);
    });
    </script>
  </body>
```

And this simple project works fine on Azure App Services.

So it could be some other part of your application which raise your issue.

You can check the `Diagnostics Logs` or leverage Visual Studio Team Services to troubleshooting the issue. Refer to the answer of [How to run django manage.py command on Azure App Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36468614/how-to-run-django-manage-py-command-on-azure-app-service) for how the enable the Team Services extension on Azure App Services.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: does it have to do anything with Linux free tier? I'm having the similar simple setup with Linux hosting and it does not work. appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a 'disconnect' handler for debugging?

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){ //add this part
   console.log('Client disconnected');    
  });
  socket.emit('get_notifications', "get_notifications_:"+new Date());
});
```

Also log at every emit and receive, so that you know when the client gets disconnected exactly. If its getting disconnected after the `get_notifications` event,  make sure you are not sending a callback to the client or that the client is not expecting a callback from the server.

I notice some missing closing braces for the `notification.find(..)` and `socket.on('userid'..)`. I hope that is only in the code that you pasted here.