# While installing HTTP_Request2 pacakage(php) in azure raises the issue

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service, pear, http-request2

I had create a webapp(**of php**) in azure now i want to install packages **HTTP_Request2**.While am installing it raises error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Azure Web Apps, we do not have sufficient permission for file system operations under `C:` path, we only can read and write files under `d:\home` path.

To install `HTTP_Request2` packages on Azure Web Apps, you can leverage `composer`.

Please try to run the command:
`composer require pear/http_request2` and `composer update` on Kudu Console site or Visual Studio online extension.

Otherwise, if you have already have `composer` extension on Azure Web Apps, you can config your `composer.json` on local before deploy to Azure.

You can refer to the answer of [How to install composer on app service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35035504/how-to-install-composer-on-app-service/35058312#35058312) for how to enable `composer` extension on Azure Web Apps.

## update

After using `composer require pear/http_request2` to install the packages, the composer will generate or update the `composer.json` file in your root directory of your application, whose contain should be similar with:

```
{
      "require": {
         "pear/http_request2": "^2.3"
      },      
      "repositories": [
        {
          "type": "pear",
          "url": "http://pear.php.net"
        }
      ],
      "minimum-stability": "dev"
    }
```

And the packages will be installed in the `vendor` folder, the `pear/http_request2` is in the path of `vender/pear/http_request2`. At the same time, `composer` will generate a file `autoload.php` in the `vendor` folder.

So, when you use `composer` to manage our packages, you can use following code to require your pacakges:
`require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: After completing above process while invoking my app causes following error **Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'HTTP/Request2.php' (include_path='.;D:\home\site\wwwroot\pear') in D:\home\site\wwwroot\php-image-api\GetTarget.php**

Comment: It seem that you used `require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';` to include the package. Please refer to my update to modify your code and try again.

Comment: composer.json contains<br/>{
    "require": {
        "pear/http_request2": "^2.3"
    }
}

Comment: Do you include the package in PHP script with the code :`require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'`?

Comment: vendor folder didn't contain any files and also autoload.php is not found in the directory

Comment: Please try to run the command `composer install` or `composer update`

Comment: while running composer update by modifying the composer.json with the code given by you leads to following issue.  **Loading composer repositories with package information Initializing PEAR repository http://pear.php.net PEAR repository from http://pear.php.net could not be loaded. Your configuration does not allow connections to http://pear.php.net/channel.xml. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details. Updating dependencies (including require-dev) - Removing pear/net_url2 (v2.2.1) - Installing pear/net_url2 (dev-master 43a8760) Cloning 43a87606daf52efe6685c92131b**

Comment: could you please describe the steps how you install the packages? And do these steps are all done on Kudu Console site? Or any other environment? Thanks for your patients.