# How to install composer globally on a Linux PHP app service?

Tags: linux, azure, azure-web-app-service, composer-php

I have an app service for my PHP 8.0 application. Azure will only allow me to use Linux which is fine, but I'm having trouble installing composer globally.

Because only files inside of /home are persisted I'm not sure where I can place the resulting `composer.phar` file, in such a way that it is included in the `PATH`, and I can't find any relevant documentation, only relevant discussion I could find was this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/3638/installing-composer-on-azure-app-service.html but it still didn't help.

Could anyone tell me either where to put `composer.phar` or whether there's a way to edit my path to point towards `/home/composer.phar`?

Thanks!

Comment: Combine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35035504/how-to-install-composer-on-app-service with your solution and you're in business!

Answer (score 1):

I found the right way.

If I echo'ed `PATH` it told me that `/home/site/wwwroot` was included in the `PATH`, so all that's needed is to move the composer file into `wwwroot` doing something like `mv composer.phar /home/site/wwwroot/composer`.

Comment: I keep my composer.phar in /home as well.